# MediaPlayer is playing file from localhost but not from HTTP server

Tags: android, mysql, http, localhost, android-mediaplayer

Android mediaplayer is playing the file from localhost URL but not from HTTP server. I have checked the file path and the permission on HTTP server everything is fine. Also, I have executed the links separately they are working but it is jus that the http link is not working when i access it from phone. I have also added all the permissions in my manifest.

Localurl = 192.168.1.3/songs/live_up.mp3

Httpurl = mydomainname.com/songs/live_up.mp3

```
private void initMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();//new MediaPlayer instance

    //Set up MediaPlayer event listeners
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source
    mediaPlayer.reset();


    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        // Set the data source to the mediaFile location
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activeAudio.getFile_path());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}
```

Somebody please help

logcat

```
06-05 15:58:04.320 16454-16476/com.example.aparna.mediaplayer D/MediaHTTPConnection: filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val= stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.1.1)
06-05 15:58:04.321 16454-16475/com.example.aparna.mediaplayer D/MediaHTTPConnection: proxy null port 0
06-05 15:58:07.129 16454-28009/com.example.aparna.mediaplayer E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
06-05 15:58:07.130 16454-16454/com.example.aparna.mediaplayer E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
06-05 15:58:07.130 16454-16454/com.example.aparna.mediaplayer D/MediaPlayer Error: MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN -2147483648
```

Comment: which device are u playing in??

Comment: lenovo vibe k5 and galaxy s6 edge

Comment: Did you tried adding http:// before your URL ?

Comment: yes i did. I added http:// before both the urls.

Comment: everything is same except that server address is replaced by the domain name in the second link. the first link is working perfectly fine by when I play the second link it gives me an Error (1,-2147483648). I have checked all the links related to this error on StackOverflow and anywhere else available but none of them helped me.

Comment: post ur log cat

Comment: I have edited my question. check the log cat over there